# How to get installed Perl version information from Windows registry.

Tags: perl

like which registry key I should be looking into to get the currently installed Perl information

Comment: How did you install Perl that it wrote information to the registry?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading from Windows registry in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30269931/reading-from-windows-registry-in-perl)

Comment: @U880D No, it's not. That other question is about reading from the registry in Perl. This question is about where in the registry information about Perl is stored (the code to read it could be in any language).

Comment: The registry doesn't contain information about programs. Some programs use it to store configuration information, but not `perl` (since `perl` is configured when it's built). File associations are in the registry, though. If you're trying to launch a Perl script, you could take advantage of that (though that would only tell you about one of the installed `perl`.)

Answer (score 0):

You won't find this information in the Windows Registry, but you can get the installed version of Perl through Perl itself.

The special Perl variable `$^V` returns a nicely formatted version string (i.e. "v5.24.1")

The special Perl variable `$]` returns a numeric representation of the Perl version, subversion, and revision of the Perl interpreter, represented as a decimal of the form X.YYYZZZ, where X is the major version / YYY is the subversion / ZZZ is the revision. For example, Perl v5.10.1 would be "5.010001"

`$]` is often more useful than `$^V` as it behaves the same on any version of Perl, whereas the output of `$^V` may differ (if returned at all).

A disadvantage of `$]` is that it's not as visually user friendly to a viewer i.e. "5.010001" could be misinterpreted as "v5.01", rather than "v5.10.1"